# Login for more application

Tags: spring, spring-security, jaas

I'm developing two java web-applications through (springDataJPA,spring and vaadin). Now I want to make a login module usable from both applications.

I worked with JAAS a few month ago, and I want any suggestion about the tecnology to use to implement it.

Can i make this using spring Security?

Can you give me any suggestion about this?

Comment: why did you tag 'oauth'?

Answer (score 0):

Use spring-security, create database with users. And use them in both web apps

Look for this tutorial:

[spring-security with database](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/)